# Android Firebase remove Google Maps markers

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-maps-markers

Trying to make a small Android app that shows the locations of people as Google Maps markers.

when the user presses a button to appear on the map, the app retrieves the users data from the Firebase JSON and shows the users on the map in real time. If a user moves, the marker moves with him (removed and recreated when his location changes).

Everything works great, except that when the user presses to leave the map, his marker remains in all the other phones even though it's deleted from the Firebase JSON.

Can anyone explain how to fix this problem? My code for retrieving the users and create markers in the map:

```
 ValueEventListener UsersActiveListener = new ValueEventListener() {

            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                for (DataSnapshot userSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {

                    UsersActive uA = userSnapshot.getValue(UsersActive.class);

                    if (uA.getUserIDcode() != firebaseauth.getCurrentUser().getUid()) {

                        Double uAlatindouble = Double.valueOf(uA.getUserlat());
                        Double uAlonindouble = Double.valueOf(uA.getUserlon());

                        LatLng uALTLG;

                        if (uAmarker != null) {
                            uAmarker.remove();
                        }

                        uALTLG = new LatLng(uAlatindouble, uAlonindouble);
                        MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();
                        markerOptions.position(uALTLG);
                        markerOptions.title(uA.getUsername());
                        markerOptions.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.usermarker));
                        uAmarker = mMap.addMarker(markerOptions);

                    }
                }
                }
```

My code for entering or leaving the map (by pressing two FABs: `goActive`, `goNotActive`):

```
 public void goActiveFAB (View view){

        isActive = true;
        FABgoActive.setVisibility(GONE);
        FABDontgoActive.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        // user in map class

        UsersActive CurrentUserActive = new UsersActive();

        CurrentUserActive.setUserIDcode(firebaseauth.getCurrentUser().getUid());
        CurrentUserActive.setUserlat(String.valueOf(mLastLocation.getLatitude()));
        CurrentUserActive.setUserlon(String.valueOf(mLastLocation.getLongitude()));
        CurrentUserActive.setUsername(currentUser.getNickname());

        groupPosShareRef.child(firebaseauth.getCurrentUser().getUid()).setValue(CurrentUserActive);

    }

    public void goNotActiveFAB (View view){

        isActive = false;
        FABgoActive.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        FABDontgoActive.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        groupPosShareRef.child(firebaseauth.getCurrentUser().getUid()).removeValue();


    }
```

Thanks!

Comment: And you have verified that when the user leaves, the Uid location is definitely set to null, correct? Does it leave behind their Uid but just set it to null?

Comment: thanks Ryan, when the user leaves, the entire node of that user in the Firebase JSON is deleted, so no trace of that user remains.

Comment: Where is uAmarker initially set and is that what says if the FireBase sees that user or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `ChildEventListener` instead, then map each marker to each user's id.

```
Map<String, Marker> markers = new HashMap();

ref.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
        UsersActive uA = dataSnapshot.getValue(UsersActive.class);

        // ...

        Marker uAmarker = mMap.addMarker(markerOptions);
        markers.put(dataSnapshot.getKey(), uAmarker);
    }

    @Override
    public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
        UsersActive uA = dataSnapshot.getValue(UsersActive.class);

        // ...

        if (markers.contains(dataSnapshot.getKey())) {
            Marker marker = markers.get(dataSnapshot.getKey());

            marker.remove();
            // or
            // marker.setPosition(newPosition);
        }

        Marker uAmarker = mMap.addMarker(markerOptions);
        markers.put(dataSnapshot.getKey(), uAmarker);
    }

    @Override
    public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        if (markers.contains(dataSnapshot.getKey())) {
            Marker marker = markers.get(dataSnapshot.getKey());
            marker.remove();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

    }
});
```

Comment: Hi Wilik, thank you. I will try to implement your code. really appreciate your help.

Comment: Wilik, worked like a charm! and when I say like a charm, it's because I don't understand exactly why it worked :) thank you so much!

Comment: Please tell which part you don't understand, I will try to explain it for you :)

Comment: I just didn't work with "hashmap" before. I understand that you made a connection between the marker and the userID and I will study about hashmaps more. I thank you so much!

Comment: you can read more about HashMap [in this documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html)

Comment: what is "ref" ?? @wilik

Comment: @Basant DatabaseReference

Comment: Thnaks @Wilik, I am new to Firebase, with a little bit delay i got it